# Clustering similar words using R

Tags: r, text, cluster-analysis, data-science

I am working with R I have two dataframes. The one contains 200000 words like "cat", "cats", "cts", "dogs", and "dog", and the other one contains words like "cat", and "dog".

I want to cluster the first dataframe and replace all the similar words with the word that fits in the second dataframe. For example, "cats" and "cts" to become "cat".

Comment: The first step for doing that is to define what you mean by similarity. It looks like you are thinking similar spelling.  For that, you should look at Levenshtein distance.  However, that will mean that "good" and "god" are similar. "read" and "red".  You need to think through what you really mean.

Comment: Yes I mean spelling mistakes or using plural. I want to classify them regards the dataframe with all the actual animals names and replace cats for example with cat so to create a histogram with the frequency of the word 'cat'.

Comment: Completely agree with @G5W. This task is no easy one and **a lot** of manual input (in form of rules, matching tables etc.) is needed. You might want to check out the package `stringdist` and more importantly the metrics available.

Comment: How will you know that cts is cats and not cuts or cots?

Comment: It seems like you are heading for something like spell correction, You might also try to use a reference corpus and use it for spell correction as proposed by Peter Norvig and implemented in R, e.g., [here](http://www.sumsar.net/blog/2014/12/peter-norvigs-spell-checker-in-two-lines-of-r/).

Comment: I used grepl to isolate the words i need. But cts is an example no the actual data. Now I need to group them

Comment: Or two cluster them using a threshold with simmilarity. I dont want just to stem them because i will ignore spelling mistakes. And spelling mistakes is something common in the data set.

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @G5W, the task requires user input. Here is an example of how that could be done

```
# we have here pre-defined choices: any match must out of 'animals'
animals <- c('cat','dog','mouse')
# here is the text we want to match
text <- c('cats', 'cuts', 'dogs', 'dawg', 'frog', 'lion')
# now we use the string distance metric
# via the package stringdist & using metric 'jw'
# c.f. ?stringdist::stringdist
vapply(seq_along(text), 
       function (k) animals[which.min(stringdist::stringdist(text[k], animals, 'jw'))], 
       character(1))
# [1] "cat" "cat" "dog" "dog" "dog" "dog"
```

Notice that for instance `lion` is matched to `dog` as that is the closest match.

To further illustrate the points made in the comment section, consider the following

```
stringdist::stringdist('cts', c('cats','cuts'), 'jw')
# [1] 0.08333333 0.08333333
```

The word `cts` is equidistant to both `cats` and `cuts`. Assume the *two* word are contained in the matching table `animals`, then in this case `which.min` would return (by default) the first instance of the minimal value, so we would obtain `cats`.

You see how this can turn out to be problematic: assume `cts` was supposed to be `cuts`, the above would yield a false value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I wanted the word lion for example not to include in the result because it doesnt belong in the first dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your question!

I’m currently out of my house and typing the proposed solution on my iPhone, but I’ll apply it to your example when I’m home.

The way to convert similar values is by using the `agrep` function. You don’t need any package for it, it’s already in R .

Please leave a comment if you need specific examples :)

Here is the functionality:

```
agrep(pattern, x, max.distance = 0.1, costs = NULL, ignore.case = FALSE, 
      value = FALSE, fixed = TRUE, useBytes = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I want to compare the two dataframe and create a new one ( a new column) so I can calculate the frequency of the word cat for example.